# iOS Universal Links (on Debug) not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

I'm attempting to check the parsing of a Universal Link on an app I'm working on from within xcode debugger. I have everything working fine for some Universal links on the release build, but I want to walk through the process on debug. But after triple checking everything it just never checks for the app association file when a link is tapped from notes or google search. (Verified from packet sniffing within Charles Proxy both from simulator AND device)

Should this be working on debug?

Comment: Did you check the link using Apple’s validation tool ? https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can debug universal link using the following method in `AppDelegate.swift` file. , **developer profile must be included with an associated domain for debugging.** , I hope this helps you.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
       print("activityType: ", userActivity.activityType)
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
            let univrsalLinkURL = userActivity.webpageURL!.absoluteString
            print(univrsalLinkURL)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Goto developer account and check provisioning profile it's content must be associated domain enabled see this image.

[image]

Comment: When you say 'developer profile must be included with an associated domain for debugging' What exactly do you mean?

Comment: see my answer I have attached an image for your help.

Comment: This is the older way, now its directly configured with app bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

Send the link in simulator message application. And click on that it will help you in debugging.